# How to pass api key in Vue.js Header?. i was used DRF pagination url

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, pagination

How to pass api key in Vue.js Header?. i was used DRF pagination url

```
methods: {
    getPostData() {
      axios
        .get("http://192.168.43.126:8000/api/?page=" + this.currentPage, {
          headers: {
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "x-api-key": "IBctIWwi.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          },
        })
```

Comment: Please format the fragment as a code

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass that way. I strongly recommend that you use this method in the bootstrap.js file (in the case of the Vue + Laravel project).

```
//bootstrap.js
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = 'yourToken';
```

Try to pass this way in native Vuejs apps. I strongly recommend that you use this method main.js (In the case of the native Vue project).
Just use this configuration at the beginning of the file and your other requests will have the token already included.

```
//main.js    
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.state.token
```

Comment: its django project, try in above script but not working